# How to create a dataframe from a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I need to create a dataframe from a list which contains 10 stocks data in a list.. but the required format is all items should be listed in one column instead of each column for each element.
The required format should look like this image below,

[image]

I tried this (the entire code),

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

xl = openpyxl.load_workbook("Stock_sample.xlsx")
sheet1 = xl["Close Price"]

all_cols = sheet1.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=10, values_only = True)

all_cols_list = []
for cols in all_cols:
    all_cols_list.append(cols)

df = pd.DataFrame (all_cols_list)
print (df)
```

the `all_cols_list` returns a list of list. When I create a df from that list, that returned a dataframe like this below,
[image]

So, don't know how to do so. please suggest a way to do the required format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list inside the list will be a new column. If you convert these lists into a single list, you can get the output you want. You can use:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([i for sublist in all_cols_list for i in sublist])
```